# Messages wont open: the Messages database is being updated

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages

Recently on my new macbook when I try to open up the messages app it won't let me open it and gives me the error:

```
Messages is updating...

The Messages database is being upgraded, please wait while it finishes or Quit Messages and relaunch it later.
```

And no matter what I do it won't go away and work.

I have tried to copy over the messages folder in Library from another computer but it didn't help at all. this is really starting to bug me and I would appreciate any help towards fixing this issue.

My macbook is running the latest version of Yosemite and is the 2014 edition

Comment: how long did you wait before making it start over?

Answer (score -1):

I've been getting the same thing on and off for a long time now. I wait for any period of time and still get the same, most always a reboot of the system makes it work again...frustrating!

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.3